# framework for atomic execution of sequence of operations

Tags: python, function, atomic, operation

I have a couple of functions with side effects (outside the program memory).

I want to write a program that executes a sequence of operations (function calls) atomically, such that if any operation of the sequence fails, operations previously executed are rolled back.

I couldn't find any library that did this, so I set out to write something myself.

My idea is  to wrap operations in a context manager, for example:

```
def f1(a):
    #a function with side effects
    pass

#...

with AtomicOperation() as a:
    a.f1( arg )
    a.f2( arg2 )
    somevariable= a_function_without_side_effects()
    a.f3( arg3 )
```

This seems feasible with some `getattr` and `partial` trickery.

Does this seem like a sensible design?

Comment: This is not possible in general.  Imagine if `f1` sends an email.  Your context manager couldn't reverse that.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Yes, of course. Let's assume that for any atomically executed function `f` we have a function `g` that reverses `f`'s side effects, and that we already know the mapping `{f:g}`

Comment: Ah okay.  Then it's possible.

Comment: [rollbackcontext](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rollbackcontext/0.1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to revert to a previous state, this is easy en database relational world. But I think your scenario is different, so [compensations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction) is a good reading for you.